# Path, passage, way, route?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am measuring a pollutant on a device from point A to B or B to A (beginning to end of a street). The device starts measurement of the pollutant, logs it at one-minute intervals, calculates the average for the entire route, and records the total duration in minutes.  Then I will start a new recording for a new route (say from G to F or C to D) or street and continue the process. As an example, the first measurement on May 06, 2011, recorded 891 ug and the total duration was 9 minutes. What can I call each of these individual routes which produced the measurements listed under pollutant? Path, passage, route, stretch or any suggestion ?

```
date    pollutant   minutes
06-May-11   891     9
06-May-11   666     7
06-May-11   360     7
06-May-11   928     11
06-May-11   1123    9
```

Comment: you can call them routes or sub-routes.

Comment: It is pretty common in the GPS field to call them [tracks](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/track) check out definition 3a.

Comment: You need to be clearer.  If the route is Oak Street to Grand Avenue to Atlantic Boulevard, do you start a new "recording" when turning from Oak to Grand, or does the recording continue uninterrupted for the entire distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Segment**!

"The part of a line that connects two points. It has definite end points."  From [www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/line-segment.html](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/line-segment.html)